# How to query foreign relations data along with multiple main records

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I have a relation `Room`. Each room has one owner which is a `User` entity, and each `Room` has multiple participants which are also `User` entity.

When the page loads, I query all rooms in React

once all the rooms are returned back, I query the database one by one with each rooms ID to get back the details of of the room stored in other relations (Room owner, room user count, room topic which is of entity `Topic`)

```js
  const fetchRooms = () => {
    const csrf: HTMLMetaElement = document.querySelector(
      "meta[name='csrf-token']"
    ) as HTMLMetaElement;
    axios
      .post(
        `/room/all/${pageNumber}`,
        {},
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf.content,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        data.forEach((room: any) => {
          //! TODO: merge each rooms details with its own data to avoid extra requests
          axios
            .post(
              "/room/details",
              { id: room.id },
              {
                headers: {
                  "Content-type": "application/json",
                  "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf.content,
                },
              }
            )
            .then(({ data }) => {
              if (data) {
                setRooms((rooms) => [
                  ...rooms,
                  <RoomCard
                    key={room.id}
                    id={room.id}
                    title={room.name}
                    img={null}
                    username={data.owner.username}
                    timestamp={room.created_at}
                    userCount={data.user_count}
                    topic={data.topic.name}
                  />,
                ]);
              }
            });
        });
      })
      .catch(({ response }) => {
        console.log(response.status, response.data);
      });
  };
```

which laravel handles

```php
// web.php
Route::controller(RoomController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post("room/all/{page:int}", "all")->name("rooms.all");
    Route::post("room/details", "details")->name("rooms.details");
}
```

```php
// RoomController.php
    public function all(Request $request, $page = 1)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return response("", 403);
        }

        $total_posts = 20;

        $rooms = Room::offset(($page - 1) * $total_posts)->limit($total_posts)->orderBy("id", "desc")->get();

        return response()->json($rooms);
    }


    public function details(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->id) {
            $room = Room::find($request->id);
            $user_count = RoomUser::where("room_id", $room->id)->count() + 1;
            return response()->json(["owner" => $room->owner, "user_count" => $user_count, "topic" => $room->topic]);
        }

        return response("", 403);
    }
```

```
DB info
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_project      |
+------------------------+
| failed_jobs            |
| migrations             |
| password_resets        |
| personal_access_tokens |
| room_users             |
| rooms                  |
| topics                 |
| users                  |
+------------------------+


Users
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username          | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email_verified_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| profile_picture   | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| privilege_level   | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


Rooms
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| topic_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| owner_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



Topics
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+




Users in rooms
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| room_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that, this is very VERY inefficient, as I have to query the details of the room separately for EACH room, this is going to be very slow after its deployed, it's even slow in my local machine.

I'm unsure as how to deal with it.

The one route I'm aware of is using relations provided by Laravel but then there's another problem

When I query all rooms, I return them as it is back. The user model functions (the functions that access the one to one and one to many etc relations) are only available in Laravel, of course they are not sent back with the response to JS.

How can I query `rooms` table and include all the information relating the room (topic, owner, all users that are in the room; their IDs are stored in `room_users`, all users count)

I'm using:

- ReactJS 17.0.2
- Laravel 9
- PHP 8.1
- MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB

Comment: You can load the relationships with the `with` keyword, and the relations will be a part of the response.

Comment: @aynber
You can post an answer which i can accept

Comment: If you provide the generated SQL, we can also approach it from that point of view.

Comment: @RickJames although it has been solved, I would be happy to provide the generated query if it helps more people, do you know where I can find the generated query?

Comment: @RaahimFareed - Alas, there are a hundred frameworks (such as Laravel); I make no attempt to learn any of them.  I just help people who get in trouble when the framework is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to aynber for helping in comments.

I solved it by using `with` function in eloquent.

In `all` function of `RoomController` I changed the query to

```php
$rooms = Room::with(["topic", "owner", "users"])->offset(($page - 1) * $total_posts)->limit($total_posts)->orderBy("id", "desc")->get();
```

The array passed to `with` needs to have function names defined in model of `Room` which are as following in my case

```php
    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
    }

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "room_users");
    }
```